# How to upload photo on windows form at runtime in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

Trying to upload image at runtime from the folder I have tryed many paths but cant get result.
Can anyone tall about it?

Comment: Maybe you could show some of the *paths* you have tried so that we can have a base for discussion?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\1.jpg");
    base.BackgroundImage = image;
}
```